# Proving the inverse partial derivative rule

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Given $f(x,y,z)=0$ , where $f$ is some function, show that $(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y})_{z}$ = $\frac{1}{(\frac{\partial y}{\partial x})_{z}}$.

I am not sure where to begin this proof. I'm thinking that this proof may be similar to the $\frac{1}{(\frac{dy}{dx})}$ = $\frac{dx}{dy}$ proof, but I may be wrong.

Comment: Assuming that $f$ is differentiable, we may write

$$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\,dz=0$$


Holding $z$ fixed, we have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$.  Hence, 

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}}=\frac1{\frac{dx}{dy}}$$as was to be shown!